# Recorded video can't be forwarded/backwarded, Using MediaRecorder API chrome extension

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, screen-recording

I am implementing a chrome extension which records the screen with microphone and after recording it generates the recorded video perfectly but the problem is that the recorded video can not be forwarded/ backwarded or start video from any point first time.

When it plays the first time after that it works perfectly but when I download this video then the problem is same. I take help from [muaz khan plugin](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/tree/master/screen-recording).

I am using this code for start recording:

```
function gotStream(stream) {

    if (cameraStream && cameraStream.getAudioTracks().length) {
        cameraStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            // cameraStream.removeTrack(track);
            stream.addTrack(track);
        });
    }

    if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function') {
        /*
         MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported is a function announced in https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder and later introduced in the MediaRecorder API spec http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/
         */
        if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/mp4;codecs=h264')) {
            var options = {
                type: 'video',
                mimeType: 'video/mp4;codecs=h264'
            };
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
            var options = {
                type: 'video',
                mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'
            };
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
            var options = {
                mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'
            };
        }
        console.log('Using ' + options.mimeType);
        recorder = new RecordRTC(stream, options);
    } else {
        console.log('Using default codecs for browser');
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    }

    recorder.streams = [stream];
    recorder.start(10);

    recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    recorder.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Error: ', e);
    };

    recorder.onstart = function() {
        isRecording = true;
        onRecording();
        console.log('Started & state = ' + recorder.state);
    };

    recorder.onpause = function() {
        console.log('Paused & state = ' + recorder.state);
    }

    recorder.onresume = function() {
        console.log('Resumed  & state = ' + recorder.state);
    }

    recorder.onwarning = function(e) {
        console.log('Warning: ' + e);
    };

    recorder.onstop = function() {
        stopScreenRecording();
    }

    stream.onended = function() {
        if (stream) {
            stream.onended = null;
        }
        recorder.stop();
    };

    if (stream.getVideoTracks().length) {
        stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            track.onended = function() {
                if (!recorder) return;
                if (!stream || typeof stream.onended !== 'function') return;
                stream.onended();
            };
        });
    }
}
```

and this for stop recording:

```
function stopScreenRecording(blob) {
    isRecording = false;

    var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        type: "video/mp4"
    });
    chunks = [];


    var file = new File([blob ? blob : ''], getFileName(fileExtension), {
        type: mimeType
    });

    DiskStorage.Store({
        key: 'latest-file',
        value: file
    }, function(success) {
        if (success) {
            chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
                popup: "popup.html"
            });
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: 'preview.html'
            });
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        setDefaults();
        // chrome.runtime.reload();
    }, 1000);

    try {
        videoPlayers.forEach(function(player) {
            player.src = null;
        });
        videoPlayers = [];
    } catch (e) {}

    // for dropdown.js
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        isRecording: 'false' // FALSE
    });

    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    setBadgeText('');
}
```

I saw another screen recorder whose video blob is like:

```
filesystem:chrome-extension://mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn/persistent/e6ad7ba1-6afe-4d45-y6f5-47e08a87e036.webm
```

and our video blob is like:

```
blob:chrome-extension://hgpenkfjeddjngnojmcmgbclkoakihhg/af3dcfa6-b990-464b-9726-e8b6022762a2
```

How can I get this type of blob?

Comment: Does the other screen recorder work correctly?

Comment: Might be because of https://crbug.com/750682

Comment: @DanielHerr yes it works perfectly

Comment: @wOxxOm sir I am using vp9 codec for recording

Comment: @DanielHerr other screen recorder which I tested is _screencastify_